# Using a variable to access a chart

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a C# WinForms application that has four chart controls used to graphically show some analysis results.

I have the code working for each graph, however in an attempt to be more efficient & re-use code I've defined a code block to:

- create the required series,
- extracts the data from a database & assigns the results to the appropriate series
- add the series to the chart
- customise the charts appearance.

All of the above is done dynamically as the data does not exist at design time.

The working code I am looking to re-use is:

```
// Add both series to the chart.  
ChartName.Series.AddRange(new Series[] { series1, series2 });  

// Cast the chart's diagram to the XYDiagram type, to access its axes.  
XYDiagram diagram = (XYDiagram)ChartName.Diagram;
```

I'd like to change the `ChartName` object to a variable that I can pass each of the charts in order to re-use the code. Something like (note this does not work):-

```
var VChart = this.Controls.Find(ChartName, true);  

// Add both series to the chart.  
VChart.Series.AddRange(new Series[] { series1, series2 });  

// Cast the chart's diagram to the XYDiagram type, to access its axes.  
XYDiagram diagram = (XYDiagram)VChart.Diagram;
```

Any ideas, hints, tips, etc on how-to pass a variable into the ChartName would be appreciated.

Full Code:

```
    void Generate_Chart()
    {
        // Create two stacked bar series.
        Series series1 = new Series("Data", ViewType.Bar);
        Series series2 = new Series("Ben", ViewType.Line);

        try
        {                    
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(m_dbConnection))
            for (int i = LoopMin; i < LoopMax; i++)
            {
                // Retrieve the actual calculated values from the database
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + Chart_SourceActualValue + " FROM " + Chart_SourceTable + " WHERE Value = " + i + "";
                Chart_SeriesA_Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                // Retrieve the expected values from the database
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + Chart_BenExpValue + " FROM " + Chart_SourceTable + " WHERE Value = " + i + "";
                Chart_SeriesB_Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                // Add the dynamically created values to a series point for the chart
                series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, Chart_SeriesA_Value));
                series2.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, Chart_SeriesB_Value));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }

        // Add both series to the chart.
        //this.Controls.Find(varChart, true)
        ChartName.Series.AddRange(new Series[] { series1, series2 });

        // Remove the GridLines from the chart for better UI
        // Cast the chart's diagram to the XYDiagram type, to access its axes.
        XYDiagram diagram = (XYDiagram)ChartName.Diagram;
        // Customize the appearance of the axes' grid lines.
        diagram.AxisX.GridLines.Visible = false;
        }        
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "pass a variable into the ChartName" ?

Comment: I did something similar using the `ref` keyword to create generic methods

Comment: I would like to re-use a variable to pass the ChartName into into the series code segment & the XYDiagram segment. Essentially I weant to use the same two lines of code for all four charts & not have eight lines of code doing the same thing with the only difference being the ChartName.

Comment: Lift it out to a function that takes chartName as a parameter?

Comment: I'm not sure what chart package you're using, but a step forward would be to change you reteival of the chart to `var VChart = this.Controls.Find(ChartName, true).FirstOrDefault(); `. Currently your Controls.Find returns an array of Control

Comment: I'm using the DevExpress chart package & think it might be useful to post the entire function I've got instead of the extracts :-

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking to replace the hardcoded `ChartName` with a variable so that you can call your routine four different times, each time with a different chart. I've taken your code and replaced some of the global variable of your chart control and settings and and made them parameters you pass into the function:

```
void Generate_Chart(DevExpress.XtraCharts.ChartControl chartCtrl,
                   string chart_sourceActualValue,
                    string chart_sourceTable,
                   string chart_benExpValue
                   )
    {
        // Create two stacked bar series.
        Series series1 = new Series("Data", ViewType.Bar);
        Series series2 = new Series("Ben", ViewType.Line);

        try
        {                    
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(m_dbConnection))
            for (int i = LoopMin; i < LoopMax; i++)
            {
                // Retrieve the actual calculated values from the database
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + sourceActualValue + " FROM " + 
                     chart_sourceTable + " WHERE Value = " + i + "";
                Chart_SeriesA_Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                // Retrieve the expected values from the database
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " + chart_benExpValue + " FROM " + 
                         chart_sourceTable + " WHERE Value = " + i + "";
                Chart_SeriesB_Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                // Add the dynamically created values 
                // to a series point for the chart
                series1.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, Chart_SeriesA_Value));
                series2.Points.Add(new SeriesPoint(i, Chart_SeriesB_Value));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }

        // Add both series to the chart.
        chartCtrl.Series.AddRange(new Series[] { series1, series2 });

        // Remove the GridLines from the chart for better UI
        // Cast the chart's diagram to the XYDiagram type, to access its axes.
        XYDiagram diagram = (XYDiagram)chartCtrl.Diagram;
        // Customize the appearance of the axes' grid lines.
        diagram.AxisX.GridLines.Visible = false;
        }        
}
```

Then, you end up calling this method like this using the original values as arguments:

```
void Generate_Chart(ChartName, Chart_SourceActualValue, Chart_SourceTable, 
                    Chart_BenExpValue);

// call it three other times passing in the different specifics for that chart. e.g.
void Generate_Chart(SomeOtherChartName, SomeOtherChart_SourceActualValue, 
                    SomeOhterChart_SourceTable, SomeOtherChart_BenExpValue);

.....
```